# Reuse java script function to Show Multiple Images Preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload

[image]

Hello!

I wrote the single java script function to show the image preview before uploading.
For single file uploading, my code is working fine.

But now i want to give multiple image uploading options by giving multiple select options to user(see the snapshot). Also for this, i want to reuse my function that is displaying the preview of selected first image.(see the image in snapshot)

How would i modify my html code and how to reuse my script function?

html

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="wrapper" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <input id="fileUpload"  name="uploadedFile" type="file"/> 
    <input  id="fileUpload2"  name="" type="file"/> 
    <input id="fileUpload3"  name="uploadedFile" type="file"/> 
    <div id="image-holder"></div>

</div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fileUpload").on('change', function() {
          //Get count of selected files
          var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
          var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
          var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
          var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
          image_holder.empty();
          if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
            if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {
              //loop for each file selected for uploaded.
              for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) 
              {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                  $("<img />", {
                    "src": e.target.result,
                    "class": "thumb-image"
                  }).appendTo(image_holder);
                }
                image_holder.show();
                reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
              }
            } else {
              alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
            }
          } else {
            alert("Pls select only images");
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: You should use strict equality `===` instead of loose equality `==` in most cases as it doesn't make you remember tons of coercion rules.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am asking about to use this the same piece of code for multiple file selections. Have you any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't answering your question, I was just making a general suggestion.

Comment: ok dear. You are most welcome !

Answer (score 0):

This is what classes are for. You are only calling your jQuery on the fileUpload Id. And if your going to use the same image holder for more than one image like this you should not be clearing it out each time.

I refactored your code a small amount. Try this.

html

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <input class="fileUploadClass" id="fileUpload"  name="uploadedFile" type="file"/>
    <input class="fileUploadClass" id="fileUpload2"  name="" type="file"/>
    <input class="fileUploadClass" id="fileUpload3"  name="uploadedFile" type="file"/>
    <div id="image-holder"></div>

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fileUploadClass").on('change', function() {
        //Get count of selected files
        var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
        var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
        var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
       // image_holder.empty();
        if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
            if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {
                //loop for each file selected for uploaded.
                for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++)
                {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                        $("<img />", {
                            "src": e.target.result,
                            "class": "thumb-image"
                        }).appendTo(image_holder);
                    }
                    image_holder.show();
                    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
                }
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Pls select only images");
        }
    });
});
```